# Delete Record in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, haml

I am having some trouble implementing a Delete route into Sinatra with Active Record. Here are the code details

Route

```
delete '/contacts/:id' do
  @contact = Contact.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @contact
   @contact.destroy
 else
   halt 404, "Contact not found"
 end
```

View

```
%table.u-full-width
        %thead
          %tr
            %th Name
            %th Phone Number
            %th
        %tbody
          - @contacts.each do |contact|
            %tr
              %td= contact.name
              %td= contact.phone_number
              %td{}
                %form{:style => "margin: .75rem auto auto .25rem", :action => "/contacts/#{@contact.id}", :method => "post"}
                  %input{:name => "_method", :type => "hidden", :value => "DELETE"}/
                  %input.button#button-delete{:type => "submit", :value => "Delete"}/
```

Stack Error

> NoMethodError at /contacts undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
>   file: contacts.haml 
>   location: block (2 levels) in singleton class 
>   line: 55

Is the :id not passing in my views? Do I need to list contact.id in my table for it to pick up? Any help or documentation would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you give 
`@contact.id` in `:action => "/contacts/#{@contact.id}"` which doesn't exist.

In fact you have `@contacts` which contains all your contacts and `contact` which is a single contact. It's normal that `@contact` is nil

Just replace it by `:action => "/contacts/#{contact.id}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that your local variable `@contact` is nil when you're attempting to render the form.

```
:action => "/contacts/#{@contact.id}"
```

are you actually passing the contact object to the contex when you are rendering this view?

Comment: I do believe so. I added the full block in the views file. Could it be the local variable is @contacts and not @contact?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error message, the error is not with how you wrote your `delete` action. Your `delete` action looks to be okay as it is. The error is in the view file corresponding to your `index` action.

In the `index` action you likely did something along the lines of: `@contacts = Contact.all` which sets the instance variable `@contacts` to a collection of contacts.

When you get to `- @contacts.each do |contact|` in your view, you are iterating over each element in the collection of contacts and defining a local variable called `contact` each time the block is run. This is what you should be referencing here `:action => "/contacts/#{@contact.id}"` instead of `@contact`.

What is happening is you are attempting to build a form that points to a delete action for each element in `@contacts`, but you are not actually referencing the contacts themselves, as `@contact` is an instance variable that has never been set. `@contact` is only set once you actually make a request that gets routed to the `delete` action.

Comment: This is a concise breakdown of the core issue. Thank you for this, it helps me understand passing the instance variable better. swapping @contact.id to contant.id did the trick.